# Passing Path to Bash Script, Shorthand notation

Tags: bash

I'm not sure if this question has been asked or answered. If it has, I apologize. I wasn't too sure what to look for, but I'm writing a bash script to take in a path from the user, my script works with absolute and relative paths. But I was wondering if there was a way to interpret the shorthand notation to these paths. For example ~/ for home or . for current or ../ for a directory up. I was having a bit of trouble figuring this out. Here is my current bash script for reference.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "What is the path you'd like me to search?"

read PASSED

while [ ! -d $PASSED ]; do
    echo "$PASSED is not a valid directory"
    echo "Please provide a valid Path"
    read PASSED
done

ls -l $PASSED | awk -v user=`whoami` '{ if($3 == user){print $0}}'
```

Comment: Could you clarify your desire, i.e. "a way to interpret the shorthand notation to these paths"? What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to be able to pass ~/some/path or ../some/path and have my script interpret it properly as a path. Because as of right now, it doesn't understand  ~/some/path as a path

Comment: `..` is an actual filename that you can access directly. `~` is shell syntax, which you'll have to add support for

Comment: What would be a good approach to adding support for ~/ ?

Answer (score 1):

`.` and `..` are not shortcuts, they're actual directory names that exist in every directory. You don't need to do anything to support this.

`~`, however, is bash syntax that you can emulate.

In the simplest case, just check for a leading `~` and replace:

```
# Read some path
printf 'Enter a path: '
IFS='' read -r mypath

# If the path starts with ~, replace it with $HOME
[[ $mypath = '~'* ]] && mypath="$HOME${mypath#'~'}"

# Show what we got
echo "The path is $mypath, aka $(realpath "$mypath")"
```

Note that this does not support the various other `~` syntaxes like `~username` or `~+`

Comment: Okay thank you, sorry for the misunderstanding on .. and .